# What are the best options to run PhantomJS/CasperJS remotely?

Tags: phantomjs, cloud, casperjs, remote-access

I made a scraper in casperJS of a client. Problem is that client has a very slow connection speed so script either time out or it takes too long to complete.

I wonder what are the best options at this moment to run the script on a remote server.
What are the best cloud solutions that can run phantomJS + casperJS?

Is there any free service that can do this ?

Or, could I run the casperJS script on a shared Cpanel web hosting ? I'm thinking if it would work to rent a cheap web host to run this script (and others for other slow conn. clients).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Shared Cpanel hosting is not a very good solution because it is shared, so they could prohibit running custom binaries and/or limit time given to execution.

I'd recomend a cheap VPS from Digital Ocean, Linode, Vultr or any from Lowendbox.com really.